# How to perform a get request with RestSharp?

Tags: windows-phone-7, restsharp

I'm having trouble figuring out how to make a GET request using RestSharp on Windows Phone 7. All of the examples show making a POST request, but I just need GET. How do I do this?

Comment: That's an inappropriate request to make. Why don't you get familiar with the technology, and write one yourself?

Comment: There are samples posted here: http://restsharp.org/category/samples/  It would be helpful if you could get started and post your source code if you get stuck.

Comment: Evan, I know this post is a bit vague. The problem is, the page you showed me is for a post request, not a get request. I would post my code if I had some to post, but I am not even at that point yet. A google search turns up irrelevant information, and I am unsure of the syntax I need to use for this rest client - which is why I don't even have code yet.

Comment: I've edited the question to be better (which any of you could have done to be helpful instead). Can we get this reopened? It's a valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is located [here](http://lukencode.com/2010/08/04/rest-web-services-in-windows-phone-7/).

The code snippet that covers your scenario is below (`request.Method` should be set to `Method.GET`):

```
public void GetLabelFeed(string label, Action<Model.Feed> success, Action<string> failure)
{
    string resource = "reader/api/0/stream/contents/user/-/label/" + label;

    var request = GetBaseRequest();
    request.Resource = resource;
    request.Method = Method.GET;
    request.AddParameter("n", 20); //number to return

    _client.ExecuteAsync<Model.Feed>(request, (response) =>
    {
        if (response.ResponseStatus == ResponseStatus.Error)
        {
            failure(response.ErrorMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            success(response.Data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Your research skills are better than mine... Thanks =)

Comment: Can you please summarize the information found in the link so that this isn't a link only answer?

Answer (score 16):

GET is the default method used by RestSharp, so if you don't specify a method, it will use GET:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://example.com");
var request = new RestRequest("api");

client.ExecuteAsync(request, response => {
    // do something with the response
});
```

This code will make a GET request to `http://example.com/api`. If you need to add URL parameters you can do this:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://example.com");
var request = new RestRequest("api");    
request.AddParameter("foo", "bar");
```

Which translates to `http://example.com/api?foo=bar`